# Several neo4j sessions with spring-data-neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

My project [blockchain2graph](https://github.com/straumat/blockchain2graph) is a batch importing data from bitcoind into neo4j. As there are lots of data, i often do session.clear.

The problem is that I have several threads importing data in a parallel way. How could i have 4 sessions for each thread ?

I need this because it seems doing session.clear while others threads are working is creating strange behaviors

Comment: What version of SDN do you use?

Comment: The one in spring boot 1.4